# Oracle CLOB storing Arabic Numbers in form of '?'

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, oracle10g, arabic

I am working on a Desktop C# Application. One of my field is of type *CLOB*. The data I enter assign perfectly well in C# based variable but upon storing value in Oracle it store number as '?'. For instance if a string is **hi۱۲۳**, upon storing it becomes **hi???**

It is only happening with number, the rest of text in Arabic text saves fine.

Upon Running query:

```
select dump(CONTENT) from MyTable
```

gives error:

```
[Err] ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

Below is the code that Insert CLOB

```
public void InsertCLOB(string SQLStatement, string str)
        {
             System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader rstOracle = null;
             System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand sqlCommandOracle = null;
             System.Data.OracleClient.OracleTransaction txn = null;
             System.Data.OracleClient.OracleLob clob = null;
             try
             {
                 if (SQLStatement.Length > 0)
                 {
                     if (myConnection.State.ToString().Equals("Open"))
                     {
                         byte[] newvalue = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
                         sqlCommandOracle =
                           new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand(SQLStatement, myConnection);
                         rstOracle = sqlCommandOracle.ExecuteReader();
                         rstOracle.Read();
                         txn = myConnection.BeginTransaction();
                         clob = rstOracle.GetOracleLob(0);
                         clob.Write(newvalue, 0, newvalue.Length);
                         txn.Commit();
                         Console.WriteLine("CLOB UPDATED");
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.TargetSite + " - " + ex.Message);
             }
             finally
             {
                 sqlCommandOracle.Dispose();
                 rstOracle.Close();
                 txn.Dispose();
                 clob.Close();
             }

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the column to NCLOB?

Comment: @Rachcha Nope, will it solve the issue?

Comment: this is my character value:
NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16

Comment: I recommend you convert that column to NVARCHAR or NCLOB as you are storing characters in multiple languages, especially RTL language like Arabic. Visit Oracle Docs for more details.

Comment: I just did, no difference. As I siad only Arabic Numerics are converted into ? not other text.

Comment: How are you inserting the data into the NCLOB column? You should use `INSERT INTO myTable (clob_column) VALUES (n'hi۱۲۳')`. Note the `n` I have put before the string literal. I don't know how C# passes the UTF characters to the CLOB column the way you have shown but you must make sure that the data passed from C# to Oracle preserves the characters. If C# is sending ? to Oracle, it will be saved as it is. Just to make sure that Oracle is not messing with the characters, run the `INSERT` statement at the back end using SQL Developer or Toad or a similar tool.

Comment: I didn't put "n" before..will try it

Comment: Ok One thing confirmed, whether putting n or not, when I run query directly via Oracle client it puts number properly, C# does something in variable or what that it sends ??, means it does not encode it no matter I put n or not.

Comment: Correct. Now check how C# supports Unicode. If it is not enabled already, enable it. If there is some other way to send Unicode characters to the database, please use it.

Comment: hmm is it UTF8 or 16?

Comment: It was a db driver issue, it was NOT reading data as Unicode, it stored other non English data as ascii text but not numbers.